# Absolute maximum ratings interpretation

Tags: datasheet, cmos, maximum-ratings

I have a [datasheet of a CD74HCT86E XOR gate](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd54hc86.pdf). Under Absolute Maximum Ratings, it says

> DC Output Source or Sink Current per Output Pin, IO
>
> For VO > -0.5V or VO < VCC + 0.5V . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .±25mA

How should I interpret this? I'm thinking of two options:

- Make sure that the sink or source current never exceeds 25mA. However, then I'm wondering why there are specifications on the output voltage: I should think these voltages follow from the current draw and the output impedance - you can't have a current independent of output pin voltage
- Make sure VO never goes below -0.5V or above Vcc+0.5V. As long as this is the case, the device will not source or sink more than 25mA. Do not exceed these voltages, or the device will sink/source more than 25mA, and magic smoke will happen.

Which is it?

Comment: Simple answer: Never design to the "Absolute Maximum Ratings". In general you would be better off to ignore these altogether to make sure you don't accidentally design your circuit in such a way as to constantly stress the part. Instead, look at the "Electrical Characteristics" or "Operating Characteristics" in the datasheet. Those are the values you need to design to.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I'm not designing to be anywhere close to these ratings. I was just wondering what would happen if one accidentally grounded an output pin for a short moment of time, and I couldn't figure it out from the datasheet.

Comment: Just making sure =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your first bullet is correct. The voltage range specification is simply saying that if operating within the specified range, the pins can handle +/- 25mA. However, if you look at the two lines above it, if you're operating above or below the specified range, the input/output diodes become the weakest link and they have a current limit of +/- 20mA before being damaged.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I think as a beginner, it's important to read the datasheets rather than just wing it, but then at least I should be able to understand the datasheet. My confusion stemmed from the fact that I didn't see the voltage limitations as a complement to the diode ratings.